# Temporary Table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

I have a table with products. The products are associated with product reviews. A 'rank' for each product is stored in the products table. The rank is calculated for each product twice a day using a Bayesian averaging strategy - via a cron job. I am displaying the products in an [ajax loading datatable](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

Here's my problem... The reviews are associated with a particular user type. There are hundreds of user types, and I'd like to allow users to either show the global product ranking or to filter the product reviews to exclude reviews submitted by different user types...and show a product list (with rankings) which is relevant to them and their user type.

What I want to do in this case is create a temporary table with only relevant reviews adding to the products average score and ranking. That way I can hit the temporary table with my ajax call... **The big issue is that datatables can only sort the displayed table based on some actual column in the database... so even if you could create a custom display table for the unique user type, you still can't sort the columns properly as their is no firm base table from which to work.**

EDIT:

Check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables?view=asciicast if you want an explanation of how this works. When the user clicks on a column header .. say "rank"... an ajax call is made which requests either the 10 highest ranked products, or the 10 lowest.. so only 10 rows are pulled from the db and sent from the client. That's why I can't sort based on a column which is not in the db. I have achieved a working model of this without ajax loading the data.. by putting all the data in the view and sorting it from there..

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to create temporary tables or how to design the table? Could you maybe add some sample data? Why would you need a "base table" to sort? You can sort a table on any column you like (it should better have an index of course, otherwise it would be slow)

Comment: Temporary table.. Do you know how to do this? Sorry for being so verbose

Comment: What I want is to have the products re-ranked after filtering out reviews that aren't relevant to the particular user class... but again, the issue is that the datatables jquery plugin can only sort the displayed table based on some actual column in the database... not by a ranking that has been calculated on the fly... that's why I'm thinking I need a temporary table generated for the user class, for the jquery plugin to interact with... so that a user may sort their own custom product ranking table